# How to i make "rows" consiting of pairs from a list of objects that is sorted based on their attributes

Tags: python, loops, sorting, rows

I have created a class with attributes and sorted them based on their level of x, from 1-6. I then want to sort the list into pairs, where the objects with the highest level of "x" and the object with the lowest level of "x" are paired together, and the second most and second less and so on. If it was my way it would look like this, even though objects are not itereable.

```
for objects in sortedlist:
    i = 0
    row(i) = [[sortedlist[i], list[-(i)-1]]
    i += 1
    if i => len(sortedlist)
        break
```

Comment: What happens if the list contains an odd number of elements?

Comment: Can you show us your input data and expect output data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using `zip`

I think the code you want is:

```py
rows = list(zip(sortedList, reversed(sortedList)))
```

However, note that this would "duplicate" the elements:

```py
>>> sortedList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> list(zip(sortedList, reversed(sortedList)))
[(1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 1)]
```

If you know that the list has an even number of elements and want to avoid duplicates, you can instead write:

```py
rows = list(zip(sortedList[:len(sortedList)//2], reversed(sortedList[len(sortedList)//2:])))
```

With the following result:

```py
>>> sortedList = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> list(zip(sortedList[:len(sortedList)//2], reversed(sortedList[len(sortedList)//2:])))
[(1, 6), (2, 5), (3, 4)]
```

### Using loops

Although I recommend using `zip` rather than a `for`-loop, here is how to fix the loop you wrote:

```py
rows = []
for i in range(len(sortedList)):
  rows.append((sortedList[i], sortedList[-i-1]))
```

With result:

```py
>>> sortedList=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> rows = []
>>> for i in range(len(sortedList)):
...   rows.append((sortedList[i], sortedList[-i-1]))
... 
>>> rows
[(1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 1)]
```